# C# VSTO AddIn LookUp field Ribbon

Tags: c#, outlook, listbox, vsto

I try to create a listbox with custom XML entries/values which appears after the user enters a text in a editBox.
The developer environment is C# Outlook 13/16 VSTO Plugin.
My problem is, I can only access with Ribbon Controls to an editBox or a comboBox.

With the comboBox I am able to add my custom XML entries like:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in source.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/path/item/value"))
        {
            RibbonDropDownItem item = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
            string text = node.InnerText;
            item.Label = text;
            this.comboBoxCompose.Items.Add(item);
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text);
        }
```

The editBox e.g. does NOT provide to add items...
The comboBox is the wrong choice for me, because it is a dropdown selection.

Is there a way to implemnet a listBox with custom results like in the picture enclosed. Do I have to combine it with an other API/library?

Would be nice if someone could help here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way. The Fluent UI provides a definitive set of controls.

You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

As a workaround you may consider creating a custom UI on the Outlook form region instead of Ribbon where you are free to use any .Net controls. See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions) for more information.

Comment: After searching a lot - I agree with you. My workaround will be loading a form when needed from the ribbon button. Thanks.